# How to auto-number groups of names in an Excel column?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

Does anyone know how can I auto-number column "B" based on column "A"?

Let me give you an example on how column A looks like:

```
John
John
Mike
Mike
Mike
Mike
Andy
Andy
Andy
Andy
Andy
Andy
Andy
```

Now I want to add numbering in column "B" based on column A, like this:

```
John 1
John 2
Mike 1
Mike 2
Mike 3
Mike 4
Andy 1
Andy 2
Andy 3
Andy 4
Andy 5
Andy 6
Andy 7
```

I need to do this for a list of 20k records so I need to find an automatic solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `COUNTIF()`.

In `B1` and drag down:

```
=COUNTIF($A$1:A1,A1)
```